# How to set dynamically spacing between elements in UIStackView?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uistackview

How to with constrains set dynamically spacing between elements in UIStackView?

If I'll try to set spacing in Attribute inspector with IPhone 7 device, I'll get something like this:

[image: XCode]

But when I'll want to simulate it with IPhone 5 device, I'll get this:

[image: IPhone5]

My text will cropped. So how to get result with non-cropping text inside all elements? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got it! Simply needed to add constraint to stackview of full page and set distribution to Fill and it's all! I spent couple days for that...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, setting the stack view distribution to .equalSpacing worked.